# SpringMVC Multiple Validation in a Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an application that requires different types of validation for different functions. I would like to set a different validator for different request. I saw some talk about a validation facade does anyone have any good examples on setting up a validation facade or allowing multiple validators in one controller.

Presently i am using the conventional way of setting the validator binder.setValidator(....)

Comment: Have you ever tried anything?

Comment: yea i am doing normal validation using the init binder where i set a validator binder.setValidator();